Computing conditional expectation from a given random variable
Let $\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$, $\mathcal{F}=2^{\Omega}$ and $\mathbb{P}(a)=\mathbb{P}(b)=\mathbb{P}(c)=1/3$, so $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space.
Let $X$ be a random variable as follows:
$$
X(\omega)=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{ $\omega=a$ } \\
2, & \text{ $\omega=b$ } \\
3, & \text{ $\omega=c$ }
\end{cases}
$$
Let $\mathcal{G}= \sigma(\{a\}) \ \subset \mathcal{F}$ .
Let $Y=\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})$ be the conditional expectation of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$, that is:
(i) $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable;
(ii) for all $G \in \mathcal{G}$, $\mathbb{E}(X; G)=\mathbb{E}(Y; G)$ .
I saw in some solution that:
$$
Y(\omega)=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{ $\omega=a$ } \\
2.5, & \text{ $\omega=b$ } \\
2.5, & \text{ $\omega=c$ }
\end{cases}
$$
Intuitively, I can understand why this is the result, since $\{a\} \in \mathcal{G}$, so $Y$ should get the same value in $a$ as $X$, and $b$ and $c$ have the same probability so each of them gets half of their original sum, but I wasn't able to prove it formally using the definition above and the properties of conditional expectation dervied from it.
Thanks!

Edit:
The example above was given as a solution to this question:

And this is the suggested solution:


I think you are mixing up two different $\sigma$-algebras. If you want to assign individual probabilities to $a,$ $b$ and $c$ then the probability space should have a finer $\sigma$-algebra than the $\mathcal F$ you are using in the conditional expectation.

Hi, I edited the post and added the original question and its provided solution, maybe I didn't understand it; I'm new to this topic. Thanks!

I think you may want to re-visit the initial chapter where a probability space is defined; in particular the role of the $\sigma$-algebra in that definition.

I think I understand what's wrong with my first definitions. Fixed it now.

The conditional expectation must be measurable with respect to $\mathcal F,$ therefore the inverse image of $Y(b)$ must belong to $\mathcal F = \{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b,c\},\Omega\}.$ Since the inverse image of $Y(b)$ contains $b,$ it can only be $\{b,c\}$ or all of $\Omega.$ This implies that $Y$ must have the same value on $b$ and $c.$ Not because of equal probabilities (this equality condition also holds if you change the distribution of $\mathbb P$ to a non-uniform one) but because the elements $b$ and $c$ cannot be distinguished by any element of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F.$

So, in this case the conditional expectation is computed only by the values of the r.v. $X$ and the given sub $\sigma$-algebra, regardless of $X$'s distribution?

The probability measure comes into play when computing the actual value of $Y(b)=Y(c)$ but not in concluding the fact that those two values must be equal. If, for example, another probability measure is used that awards $1/2$ to $b$ and the remaining $1/6$ to $c,$ then $Y(b)=Y(c)=2.25$

Since for this probability measure $EX=EY=11/6$?

Since for this probability measure the integral of $X$ over ${b,c}$ is $21/2+31/6=1.5$ and the measure of ${b,c}$ (the probability of the event ${b,c}$) is $2/3.$

Got it, thanks a lot!

\begin{gather*}
P_{X/\mathcal{G}}(A)=\frac{P((X\in A)\cap\{a\})}{P(\{a\})}I_{\{a\}}(X)+\frac{P((X\in A)\cap\{b,c\})}{P(\{b,c\})}I_{\{b,c\}}(X)\\
E[X/\mathcal{G}](\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^3iP_{X/\mathcal{G}}(\omega)(\{i\})=
\begin{cases}
1.1+2.0+3.0      & if \quad  \text{ $\omega=a$ } \\
1.0+2.1/2+3.1/2  & if \quad  \text{ $\omega=b$ } \\
1.0+2.1/2+3.1/2  & if \quad  \text{ $\omega=c$ }
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}
